# Fastest way in python to search for multiple items in a body of text

Tags: python, list, search

I have a long list of short strings and I want to search for all of these items in a (usually) long string of text. My list has a length of ~500 short strings and I want to find all that occur in a source text that is about ~10,000 characters long using python.

Here is a short example of my problem:

```
cleanText = "four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth on this continent a new nation conceived in Liberty and dedicated to the proposition that all men are created equal"
searchList = ["years ago","dedicated to","civil war","brought forth"]
```

My current method for finding the items in searchList that occur in cleanText is:

```
found = [phrase for phrase in searchList if phrase in cleanText]
```

Is this the fastest way in python? It's not exactly slow, but at scale (500 items in searchList with a cleanText that is 10,000 characters long) it seems a little slower than I would like.

Comment: Is your content somehow persistent? Could you use a fulltext indexing solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try a regular expression.  That might speed things up for large lists:

```
import re
found = re.findall('|'.join(searchList),cleanText)
```

(of course, this assumes that there's nothing in `searchList` that will need to be escaped for the purposes of `re`.)

---

As pointed out in the comments (thanks to anijhaw), you can do the escaping via:

```
found = re.findall('|'.join(re.escape(x) for x in searchList), cleanText)
```

You can also pre-compile the regex if you'll be using it more than once with `re.compile` e.g:.

```
regex = re.compile('|'.join(re.escape(x) for x in searchList))
found = regex.findall(cleanText)
```

**disclaimer** These solutions only find *non-overlapping* matches.

Comment: You can use re.escape for that

Comment: and also compile your regex if you are going ot use it more than once

Comment: @anijhaw -- pre-compiling really only saves you if you the re.escape step as long as you're not using *lots* of regexes in your program since `re` caches the first few internally for efficiency.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski -- Some people don't like `re`?  Maybe this isn't actually faster and therefore it's not a solution ... I don't know either.  Oh well.  I'm not offended (and I'm happy to improve on this answer if anyone leaves me a comment on how it might be made better :).

Comment: The only problem with this solution is if two of the searched-for strings overlap, they won't both be found with the regex.  But for many (500) search strings, this will certainly be faster.

Comment: @NedBatchelder -- Added a disclaimer at the end.

Comment: mgilson, that's a good point. my searchList is static. it's the cleanText that changes. I want to use the searchList to search many different bodies of text.

Comment: @user1521440 -- Is there any chance of an overlap in searchList?  e.g. searchlist looks something like `["dog cat", "cat mouse"]`?.  Of course, it could be even more silly like `["foo", "orchestra"]`, but it seems unlikely that you would have `"foorchestra"` in your `cleanText` based on the example you've provided ...

Comment: @mgilson, yes, there is a chance of overlap...but it's very small. I'll probably use your suggestion and go with speed over 100% accuracy here, as I'm searching thousands of bodies of text with my searchList. I'm going to run a test to make sure, and probably update my post. Thanks.

Comment: @anijhaw -- downvotes happen.  It's not worth worrying about.  If it's a good answer, then the upvotes will more than make up for it :).

Comment: If you use this method and any of your search terms contain items in sub groups (AKA if you use parenthesis in any of the regex terms being `OR`'ed together, you must use the `regex.finditer()` function or else they all come up blank when you try to retrieve the matched strings.